# Using perf_event_open to monitor Docker containers

Tags: performance, docker, linux-kernel, perf, linux-containers

I wrote a program in C to retrieve performance events such as cpu-cycles of Docker containers.
I mean, a user space program at host level (host level monitoring, not inside docker). I give pid of the docker container as pid entry of **[perf_event_open()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html)**, However, I have always **0** as returned value. I have tested the program for other non-docker pids for example firefox and it works very well.

I set **PERF_FLAG_PID_CGROUP** as flag, nothing changes!
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/perf_event.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>

    static long perf_event_open(struct perf_event_attr *hw_event, pid_t pid, int cpu, int group_fd, unsigned long flags)
   {
       int ret;

       ret = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, hw_event, pid, cpu,
                      group_fd, flags);
       return ret;
   }

   int
   main(int argc, char **argv)
   {
       struct perf_event_attr pe;
       long long count;
       int fd;

       fd = open("/sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event/docker/f42c13cd9dd700544fe670e30d0b3216bdceaf01ddc370405618fdecfd10b26d", O_RDONLY);
       if (fd == -1)
          return 0;

       memset(&pe, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
       pe.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
       pe.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
       pe.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES;
       pe.disabled = 1;
       pe.exclude_kernel = 0;
       pe.exclude_hv = 0;

       fd = perf_event_open(&pe, fd, -1, -1, PERF_FLAG_PID_CGROUP);
       if (fd == -1) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Error opening leader %llx\n", pe.config);
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
       ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);

       usleep(100);

       ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, 0);
       read(fd, &count, sizeof(long long));

       printf("Used %lld instructions\n", count);

       close(fd);
   }
```

According to the Man page of perf_event_open(), I also give the fd opened on the directory of docker container in groupfs. Doesn't work !

Would you please help me to solve the problem?
Thanks

**Update:**
I have checked with other events for example PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_REFERENCES,
I see **0** as returned value!

***OS: Ubuntu 16.04***

***Kernel: 4.15.0-041500-generic***

***Architecture: X86_64***

Comment: Some sample code, please?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please add some more info to your question? Add things with this in your mind: *Questions are supposed to include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified which linux kernel version you are using. I will base my answer as per the latest linux kernel version.

The parameters that you passed to `perf_event_open` syscall look correct, except for one.

In your case, you pass **cpu = -1** as a parameter to `perf_event_open`.

While this usually works in normal `perf event` filtering (i.e. per-cpu or per-thread), passing `cpu = -1` will not work in cgroup based filtering for `perf`. In cgroup mode, the `pid` argument is used to pass the fd opened to the cgroup directory in `cgroupfs` (which you seemed to have passed correctly). The `cpu` argument designates the cpu on which to monitor threads from that cgroup. And when `cpu=-1` it means the `perf event` measures the specified process/thread on any CPU (without regarding whether that CPU belongs to the cgroup you are measuring on).

[This](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.16/source/kernel/events/core.c#L10454) is how it is depicted in the latest Linux code.

`if ((flags & PERF_FLAG_PID_CGROUP) && (pid == -1 || cpu == -1))
        return -EINVAL;`

You can clearly see that if either `PID=-1 or CPU=-1`, the syscall method will return error.

---

**Working Example**

From the `perf_event_open` documentation, it is quite clear that --

`cgroup monitoring is available only for system-wide events and may therefore require extra permissions.`

Since we are doing cgroup monitoring in this case, which is already understood  as we are monitoring the `perf-events` of a container, we will have to monitor the event system-wide. This means the monitoring happens for **ALL** the available CPUs in the system.

Working code

I have 4 cores in my system and hence I use CPUs - 0,1,2,3

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/perf_event.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

    static long perf_event_open(struct perf_event_attr *hw_event, pid_t pid, int cpu, int group_fd, unsigned long flags)
   {
       int ret;

       ret = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, hw_event, pid, cpu,
                      group_fd, flags);
       return ret;
   }

   int
   main(int argc, char **argv)
   {
       struct perf_event_attr pe;
       long long count, count1, count2, count3;
       int fd, fd1, fd2, fd3, fd4;

       fd1 = open("/sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event/docker/001706b1a71617b0ce9d340f706d901e00ee398091dd62aded2a1863fc8c274a", O_RDONLY);
       if (fd1 == -1)
          return 0;

       memset(&pe, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
       pe.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
       pe.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
       pe.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_INSTRUCTIONS;
       pe.disabled = 1;
       pe.exclude_kernel = 0;
       pe.exclude_hv = 0;

       fd = perf_event_open(&pe, fd1, 0, -1, PERF_FLAG_PID_CGROUP|PERF_FLAG_FD_CLOEXEC);
       if (fd == -1) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Error opening leader: %s\n", strerror(errno));
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }
       fd2 = perf_event_open(&pe, fd1, 1, -1, PERF_FLAG_PID_CGROUP|PERF_FLAG_FD_CLOEXEC);
       if (fd2 == -1) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }
       fd3 = perf_event_open(&pe, fd1, 2, -1, PERF_FLAG_PID_CGROUP|PERF_FLAG_FD_CLOEXEC);
       if (fd3 == -1) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       } 
       fd4 = perf_event_open(&pe, fd1, 3, -1, PERF_FLAG_PID_CGROUP|PERF_FLAG_FD_CLOEXEC);
       if (fd4 == -1) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
       ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);

       ioctl(fd2, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
       ioctl(fd2, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);

       ioctl(fd3, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
       ioctl(fd3, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);

       ioctl(fd4, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
       ioctl(fd4, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);

       sleep(10);   // using sleep(10) to actually observe instructions

       ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, 0);
       ioctl(fd2, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, 0);
       ioctl(fd3, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, 0);
       ioctl(fd4, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, 0);

       read(fd, &count, sizeof(long long));
       read(fd2, &count1, sizeof(long long));
       read(fd3, &count2, sizeof(long long));
       read(fd4, &count3, sizeof(long long));

       printf("Used %lld instructions\n", count+count1+count2+count3);

       close(fd);
       close(fd2);
       close(fd3);
       close(fd4);
  }
```

`

Output : `Used 55174 instructions`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with you on the cpu parameter. I set --cpuset-cpus="0" for the docker, and passed cpu=0 to perf_event_open(). However, I always have 0 as returned value. Nothing changes ! What is the problem?

Comment: @M.B can you check with some other hardware events as well ? Something like cache_misses or the number of instructions - please report if you see 0 as well in those cases. **Also please describe your system architecture and the Linux version and flavor that you are using**. Please update that in the question.

Comment: @A.Kaltia:Thank you, I added other information to the question.

Comment: @M.B. instead of running `usleep(100)`  between enabling and disabling the events, can you run a dummy loop of 1-2 billn iterations ? Can you then calculate the `cpu-cycles` and other hardware events ? CPU time during sleep does not belong to current process!!

Comment: @ Arnabjyoti Kalita. thanks, I do exactly as you said, instead of running usleep(100) between  enabling and disabling, I put a for loop, nothing changed!. Did you test this program on your computer with a docker container?

Comment: Hi @M.B. I have managed to obtain non-zero values for some `perf events` like `PERF_EVENT_HW_INSTRUCTIONS`. I will be updating my answer soon.

Comment: @arnabjyoti.kalita. which OS do you use? I updated my kernel to the last version (4.19.1) and I run your code as root, I have 0! is there any particular configuration on your system? thank you.

Comment: Are you using all of your CPU cores while calling `perf_event_open` ? I use 4.18 kernel. Remember that only system-wide events can be monitored when `cgroups` based monitoring is involved. If you are still stuck, please run
`perf stat -e instructions --cgroup=docker/001706b1a71617b0ce9d340f706d901e00ee398091dd62aded2a1863fc8c274a -a sleep 10` and see if you get any non-zero value now.

Comment: I want to monitor instruction and cache events (cache miss, cache references) to evaluate the performance of docker, is it works in this case?

Comment: Yes it will work. `perf stat` internally uses `perf_event_open` system call to monitor performance counters. You can do an `strace perf stat -e instructions... ` to actually see this. But yes please read the man pages for `perf stat` first.

Comment: @ Arnabjyoti Kalita , Thank you very much for your responses/comments. I have always 0 as return value of perf_event_open. I don't know why. I run exactly your code. It doesn't work! on my pc. I have a 4 cores CPU.

Comment: The last thing I can say is try with a larger value of `sleep`. Something like `sleep(60)`. Can you do -- `strace perf stat -e instructions --cgroup=docker/<container-id> -a sleep 10` ? Can you see how `PERF_EVENT_OPEN` is being called within the strace output ?

Comment: @ Arnabjyoti Kalita ,Thank you. when I run the program and strace it, in debug info, I found  this : access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory), What is this? this is the only thing that goes wrong in the execution of the program.

Comment: @M.B. there are plenty of answers here regarding this. I believe this should not cause a problem. If it was, the operation would've failed even before completion. Only thing I can suggest is just make sure that all of the CPU cores are being used. For 4 cores, you should see 4 `PERF_EVENT_OPEN` syscalls. Try with a larger value of `sleep`. **Remember, only system-wide events can be measured when you do cgroup monitoring**.

Comment: I have exactly 4 cores. I monitor all 4 cores. In fact, I use your code but does not work for me! I upgraded my kernel to 4.19. All things OK.  it is wonderfull! I am trying to solve the problem and I will say you when I found the problem.